# Cleaning up git repo *and* preserving commits after evil acts

Tags: git, github

I did an evil thing in github: used rebase, then push --force. This was because I wanted to change the name associated with my commits, and have it reflected in the repository.

As is warned elsewhere, this can have consequences for other upstream or downstream repos.

The consequence I am seeing is duplicate commit messages in the upstream repo after they did a merge.

We have the following structure:

Main (fairly inactive)
     - Evil (very active)
     - Others (very inactive)

My question is: how do I get Main into a good state if is already has a few commits. My suggested plan of action is:

- git clone Main
- git reset [pre-merge-commit]
- git stash
- git push --force
- git stash pop
- git push

I am a little reluctant to do this without being sure it will (a) fix the problem and (b) not create more disasters. The 'Evil' respository has been very active since it performed its own reset/push, and I assume that they will need to do something like:

- git pull
- git reset [largest-commit-that-still-exists-on-Main]
- git stash
- git push --force (to revert 'Evil' to a state that exists in Main)
- (pull stuff from Main and merge normally)
- git stash pop
- git push (to apply local changes)

Is this right?

Finally, the 'Evil' repository has numerous commits done after it did the reset/push. Is there any way to ensure all the commit messages are preserved when it resyncs with Main?

Comment: Doing some more research, I am wondering if a combination of git-fetch and git-cherry-pick might be a better answer, then once the Main repo has all the updates and looks good, just force the updates on all the children. Or vice verca: get 'Evil' into a current and accurate representation of the source and history, then force it (somehow?) onto Main.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from what you've described, I'd say probably your best bet would be the second possibility mentioned in your comment - namely, continue to modify "Evil" until it is as accurate as possible, then have "Main" reset to where Evil is. Any downstream users can rebase (using the `--onto` flag) onto the "new world order" from "Evil".

Comment: Ooops. Hit return too soon.....is there a simple way to get the upstream respository (Main) to reset to match Evil once it is in a good state?

Comment: Sure. From a clone of the Evil repository, just `git push --force <main> master` (assuming `master` is the branch in question).

Comment: (Of course, this assumes that you have access to the upstream repo. If you don't, someone who does will need to do the above.)

Comment: Ended up doing a combination of rebases and cherry picking